# ¿Que hacer si no me detecta la libreria iostream em C?

Tags: c, linux

Soy usuario de Linux y al momento de compilar un programa en Lenguaje C no me detecta la libreria iostream
¿tengo que actualizar algo o como?
Estaba trabajando antes compilando desde la terminal pero ahora descargue codeblocks aun no

Comment: Compila desde terminal, los IDEs son malignos.

Comment: Lo he intentando pero sigue sin detectar la libreria ):

Comment: No sé si sabías, pero la librería `iostream` es de C++, su equivalente en C sería `stdio.h`.